source-block appears to expand the contents of a string expression when executed
What could be going on with the execution of this sh source-block on my system?
#+begin_src sh
MY_VAR="SELECT * from myTable"
echo $MY_VAR
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: SELECT file1.org file2.org from myTable

where file1.org and file2.org are in the same directory as the org document containing the executed source block.
However, if I do the same, but specify shell instead of sh, I get a more reasonable result.
#+begin_src shell
MY_VAR="SELECT * from myTable"
echo $MY_VAR
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: SELECT * from myTable

How is it possible for the sh block to interpret the * in the string as an expression it needs to expand?

I can reproduce the expanded result with both sh and shell and I can reproduce that from a command line shell as well. Try it. If you don't want the expansion, you need to quote the argument of echo: echo "$my_var". And this has nothing to do with Emacs or Org mode: it's purely a shell thing.
